# How to load different custom cells in tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

I am facing problem with multiple custom cell in table view. For different custom cell I have used different cell identifier. But cell content is visible after some time when I scroll up table.
See the first image [image]

After up scrolling cutting cell shown properly [image]

Cell height is depending on string. Both cell created using code not from nib file.

Please help me. Give me some example to how handle different custom cell into one tableview.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303832/uitableview-with-two-custom-cells-multiple-identifiers

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to use different custom cells in method cellForRowAtIndexPath for different cases.

So you should write some conditions where you will describe witch class for cell should be used as for example I use the number of the indexPath.row which means that the number of the row from the top (when you write condition indexPath.row == 1 so it basically means top row or top cell in the section of the tableView):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell

    //case 2:
    //...  some other cases you need
    //case n:

    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThirdTableViewCell
  }
return cell 
}
```

But you have to make different classes for your cell to meet your own requirements for each cell.
Hope it helps.