# UITableViewCell Nib From NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, custom-cell

I am trying to change the custom cell that will be used depending on information stored in my array. I have tried everything but cannot seem to get it working without an error. The code does not seem to accept a string input for the cell nib. Is there any other way to do this? Will attach my code below.

Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    if([[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"reply"]  isEqual: @"N"])
    {
        nib = @"ReviewCell1";
    }
    else{
          nib = @"ReviewCell2";
    }
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = nib;



    ReviewCell1TableViewCell *cell = (ReviewCell1TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)

    {

        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nib owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    if ([[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"stars"]  isEqual: @"1"]){
        NSLog(@"1");
        cell.star1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star6.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];

    }
    else if ([[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"stars"]  isEqual: @"2"]){
        NSLog(@"2");
        cell.star1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star6.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];

    }
    else if ([[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"stars"]  isEqual: @"3"]){
        NSLog(@"3");
        cell.star1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star6.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
    }
    else if ([[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"stars"]  isEqual: @"4"]){
        NSLog(@"4");
        cell.star1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
        cell.star6.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];
    }
    else if ([[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"stars"]  isEqual: @"5"]){
        NSLog(@"5");
        cell.star1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star6.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greystar.png"];

    }
    else if ([[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"stars"]  isEqual: @"6"]){
        NSLog(@"6");
        cell.star1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        cell.star6.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];

    }


    cell.reviewdate.text = [Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"date"];
    cell.reviewtext.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ -%@",[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"desc"],[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"]];

    //cell.tutortext.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ -%@",[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"desc"],[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"]];







    cell.tutortext.text = @"this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test";






    return cell;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303832/uitableview-with-two-custom-cells-multiple-identifiers - might be solve your problem.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

You have to register your nib file preferably in your `viewDidLoad`

Sample code :

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:self.cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

and then use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` normally as you have done already. you can register multiple `nib` files with different identifiers and just dequeue them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with their unique identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

In my projects I often do a base cell with class methods like this:

```
+ (NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}

+ (UINib *)nibName {
    return [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:nil];
}
```

And all other cells subclass from it and use it this way where it needed:

```
 [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:[FeedCell nibName] bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:[FeedCell reuseIdentifier]];
```

Hope it helps)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest , Rather then multiple `xib` file you need to create single `xib` file and you get the object from `NSArray`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = nib;

    ReviewCell1TableViewCell *cell = (ReviewCell1TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nib owner:self options:nil];

         if([[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"reply"]  isEqual: @"N"]){
               cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
         }else{
              cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:1];
         }
    }


    return cell;
}
```