# How to remove the ">" in Table View Cell and delete cell in since every index is in different indexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a problem with this. What I did was every cell in `indexPath.row % 2 == 1` I want to set it to blank so there could be a margin. But now it looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove the ">" in the cell that serves as a margin. How to remove that and remove the highlight thing when pressed? When pressed it turns to grey.

And how to delete the cell with this logic since every row is in odd numbers but the actual object is still in their proper indexes.

Here's my code:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID2];

    if (cell2 == nil) {
        cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CELL_ID2];
        [cell2.contentView setAlpha:0];
        cell2.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    }
    return cell2;
}
```

Comment: You might also take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216839/how-to-add-spacing-between-uitableviewcell) for some other options for space between cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID2];

    if (cell2 == nil) {
        cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CELL_ID2];
    }

    cell2.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell2;
}
```

Your cell configuration (if cell is nil) should contain the bare minimum of what you need because the cells get reused (`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`). So you need to configure every indepedant part of the cell when it is reused. Thus you need to set the properties you need for that row of the indexPath.

Comment: The arrow still remains..

Comment: What is the rest of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath?`

Answer (score 1):

Just set `cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;`

Comment: I don't know why but the arrow still remains. :|

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `accessaryType` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`

```
cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAcessoryNone;
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellAccessoryType