# spacing between UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a ios app in swift and want to add spacing between cells like Facebook (pic bellow).

I am using a custom nib for the posts. I know to use UITableViewController. I figure I would use a separator style but it does not achieve the effect. I goggled around for hours and can't find a single tutorial in swift that makes sense! could some one explain how they did it in there app using swift? thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have a wrapper view inside the cell's content view. Inset that with, like, 10px for all edges. Then put your content inside that view. Or use collection view.

Comment: easy way is make your nib view height 10px more... with clear background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add spacing between UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216839/how-to-add-spacing-between-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 35):

This is my solution with result: (based on Jorge Casariego's answer)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomApplicationCell

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 8, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 149))

    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2

    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedView)

    return cell
}
```

table row height: 165 point

header section height, footer section height: 10 point

> and result

[image]

**Edit For Swift 3 Syntax:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomApplicationCell

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 120))

    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2

    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)

    return cell
}
```

---

> **Simplest way for creating material card view:**

[github.com/SwiftCardView](https://github.com/ibrahimyilmaz7/SwiftCardView)

Create **CardView.swift**

```
@IBDesignable
class CardView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 2

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 3
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? = .black
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight)
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    }
}
```

**Now just add CardView class to your UIView.**

Comment: when you going to edit rows background view not move accordingly.

Comment: Im using the same code as yours in swift 3, and granted it is changed to swift 3 syntax but I get no where near your type of cells...

Comment: @return0 i've added the converted codes. The same code worked without any changes.

Comment: It should be `UIColor.clear` instead of  `transparentColor`

Comment: I want to change the background colour? Can you help me

Comment: Background of table or cell?

Comment: You are amazing dude ! Thank you so much

Comment: The class CardView: UIView produces a lot of these errors in xCode 10.0 beta `Property cannot be marked @IBInspectable because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`

Answer (score 27):

With Swift 2 you can do spacing between UITableViewCells in this way:

In your TableViewController copy this:

```
    // In this case I returning 140.0. You can change this value depending of your cell
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 140.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.frame.size.width, 120))

        whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
        whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2

        cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
        cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedView)
    }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView) and cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedView) are called each time you display cell. You do not remove them and spam shadows and views this way

Answer (score 14):

I spent at least an hour researching the topic. Finally, I came up win an idea to use a transparent border:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "faqCell", for: indexPath)

    // ...

    cell.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(TABLE_CELLSPACING)
    cell.layer.borderColor = tableView.backgroundColor?.cgColor

    return cell
}
```

This works perfectly in Swift 3/Xcode 8.

[Image: This is how it looks like on my side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjUMo.png)

Comment: few hours and finally found you.. T-H-A-N-K  Y-O-U

Comment: It's the most convenient solution I've found so far. However it's interesting that it doesn't work for clear color option. Does anyone know the reason of it?

Comment: It's a good thought, but it ended up clipping the text for me, so I couldn't use it.

Answer (score 6):

code for Swift 4

```
override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set (newFrame) {
            var frame =  newFrame
            frame.origin.y += 4
            frame.size.height -= 2 * 5
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have right / legal spacing, not a trick, you can try UICollectionView instead of UITableView.

UICollectionView is more generic than UITableView, and you can custom almost thing on it.

Comment: Agree ^_^. Also we can put a UIView inside a cell as a space between two cells.

Comment: Although using Collection View is good solution for this problem, keep in mind that you do not have the native Swipe to Delete option.

If you need that, you will either hack the spacing between cells in table view, or hack the swipe to delete in collection view. :)

Comment: @Boris I don't think Swipe to Delete in CollectionView is a hack, it's a feature. Otherwise, TableView doesn't have "Swipe to delete", you can only turn on edit mode, "swipe to reveal a button" then tap on it to delete.

Answer (score 2):

There are many right answers here.

The easiest way I found, was to create a container view inside the cell's contentView in Interface Builder. Then put all your cells meaningful content inside that and constrain to that view.

Constrain the container view according to your padding requirements.

Something like:

[image]

[image]

Then in your tableViewCellForRow add the following (assuming your container view outlet is called containerView).

```
    currentCell.containerView?.layer.cornerRadius = 8 // Your choice here.
    currentCell.containerView?.clipsToBounds = true
```

// Add borders, shadows etc. if you'd like.

Looks like

[image: rounder corners]

Answer (score 1):

I made a subclass of UITableViewCell and a nib file to go with it. Drag a UIView into the **contentView** of the cell and to start with, make it the same size as contentView. This will act as a container and become the "new" contentView. You can put what you need in there, just like you would normally in the contentView of a UITableViewCell.

Now you can adjust the height of the container view to leave your desired spacing at the bottom of the cell. Finally, change the background color of the **contentView** to **clearColor**, which will complete the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C version for Jorge Casariego Swift code:

```
//play with the 'y' parameter of the whiteRoundedView to change the spacing 
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:225/255.0 green:225/255.0 blue:225/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIView  *whiteRoundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, self.view.frame.size.width-10, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
    CGFloat colors[]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};//cell color white
    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors);
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false;
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedView];
    [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedView];
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //assign the right cell identifier
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableView]dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

These methods will help you to achieve the spacing:-

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 15;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
UIView *invisibleView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds .size.width, 15)];
[invisibleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
return invisibleView;

}
```

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection = 1 ???????????? then Why do I need a space?

Answer (score -2):

There 2 possible solutions:
1) Use `UICollectionView` with vertical layout. This is really flexible solution, you can write you [own layout](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html) for collection. [Some amazing results with custom layout](https://github.com/AlexandrGraschenkov/HW_CollectionCustomLayout/blob/master/example.gif)
2) Like @sikhapol has commented. But you will have problems with highlight cell. In my project I create common cell with `content` outlet view, witch contains all content view.

```
class ShadowContentCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var content: UIView!
    private var contentBg: UIImageView!
    private var contentOverlay: UIImageView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.frame = super.frame
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // custom higlight color
        selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = nil
        contentBg = UIImageView(frame: content.bounds)
        contentBg.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        contentBg.image = UIImage(color: content.backgroundColor)
        content.addSubview(contentBg)
        content.sendSubviewToBack(contentBg)

        contentOverlay = UIImageView(frame: content.bounds)
        contentOverlay.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        contentOverlay.highlightedImage = UIImage(color: UIColor(white: 0.000, alpha: 0.2))
        content.addSubview(contentOverlay)
    }

    override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        contentOverlay.highlighted = highlighted
        if animated {
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.3
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            transition.type = kCATransitionFade

            contentBg.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
        }
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    }
}
```

Comment: view controller does not have frame error?! how do i fix this?