# Adding space between tableviewcell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to adding space between dynamic cells.

That is my code. I didn't understand why its not working.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footer = UIView()
        footer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return footer
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spacing between UITableViewCells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598830/spacing-between-uitableviewcells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by setting your numberOfRows in section to 1 and setting your numberofSections to the array of dynamic items that populate the cells. You could then set the footer view height to your desiered space.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return YOUR_DESIRED_SPACE_BETWEEN_CELLS
}
```