# How can I create space between table view cells using constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

[image: a screenshot of my storyboard]

As you can see in the screenshot, there's no space between the top image and the top of the screen. Also, all my images are not the same size. How can I create space between these cells and also make all the images the same size.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598830/spacing-between-uitableviewcells

Answer (score 0):

You could create a height constraint on the `UIImageView`. Then create an aspect ratio constraint and set it to something like 16:9. Then set the `contentMode` property of the `UIImageView` to **AspectFill** and turn on **Clip To Bounds**.

Then constrain the top of the `UIImageView` to the top of the cell, the bottom to the bottom and the trailing to the trailing with a constant of 15 (or whatever) for every one.

Create a Centre-Y (Centre Vertically) and a Horizontal spacing constraint between the `UILabel` and the `UIImageView`.

To stop the label from clipping create a trailing constraint between it and the cell and set the value to **>= 15** or something. Then set the **Number Of Lines** property to 2 (setting it to 0 could cause clipping at the top and bottom of the cell if the name is ridiculously long running on an iPhone 4/4s/5).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest go for **collection views** you can manage cell spacing easily-:

1) Add `collection view` on storyboard.

2) Add its `DataSource` and `Delegate` in similar way to table view.(select collection view, and drag drop to yellow icon).

3) Add `imageView` on cell.

4) Adjust `cell` size accordingly.

5) Also to provide cell spacing check below image.

[image]

6) Adjust **minimum spacing for lines** it will provide what you looking for.

**Controller Class-:**

```
import UIKit

//controller class with 3 needed protocols
class UnderlineViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    //viewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        }
    //didReceiveMemoryWarning
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //numberOfItemsInSection
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 5
    }


    //dequeueReusableCell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    //numberOfSections

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    // sizeForItemAt for each row
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT-:**

[image]

Also uncheck `scrollViewInsets`.

1) Click on yello icon of your controller and select `Attribute Inspector`.

2) Look for Adjust Scroll View Insets and uncheck it.

[image]