# Show two different custom cells in same uitableview - swift firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am currently having a problem with displaying two different types of custom cells on the same uitableview.

What I have managed so far, is receiving the "updates" to the update cell, known as `cell`. I just cannot figure out how to also get numberOfRowsInSection to return two values, so both of my cells will show.

**Let me explain through my code:**

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return updates.count
        return updatesTask.count // I CANNOT DO THIS - what can I do instead?
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:updateTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! updateTableViewCell
        let cellTask:tasksTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tasksTableViewCell


        let update = updates[indexPath.row]
        let updateTask = updatesTask[indexPath.row]


        // Example of the two different cells that need different data from firebase
        cell.nameLabel.text = update.addedByUser
        cellTask.nameLabel.text = updateTask.addedByUser
```

As you can probably see, the `let updateTask` is trying to get an `indexPath.row` but that is not possible, since I cannot have two return values in the `numberOfRowsInSection`, which is a problem because that number is referring to the place where the data is stored in my firebase database.. How can I modify this to make it work?

Hope you guys understand where I am going with this, otherwise let me know and I will try to explain better :-)

Comment: Please add the rest of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as that is important in this situation too.

Comment: And please tell me in what order do you want to display the two different cells? all Cells followed by all TaskCells?

Comment: @SamM that is all of my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` at the moment, more to come later if I get this to work, and I would like to display the cell before the cellTask - if it is possible?

Comment: Check my answer, it will display all cells followed by all cellTasks. If you need them to be like cell/cellTask/cell/cellTask... tell me and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I would much rather have that! That would be awesome! @SamM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Callam's answer is great if you want to put them in two sections.

This is the solution if you want all to be in one section.

First, in `numberOfRowsInSection` method you need to return the sum of those two array counts like this: `return (updates.count + updatesTask.count)`

Then you need to configure `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row < updates.count{
        // Updates
        let cell:updateTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! updateTableViewCell
        let update = updates[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = update.addedByUser
        return cell
    } else {
        // UpdatesTask
        let cellTask:tasksTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tasksTableViewCell
        let updateTask = updatesTask[indexPath.row-updates.count]
        cellTask.nameLabel.text = updateTask.addedByUser
        return cellTask
    }

}
```

This will display all cells followed by all cellTasks.

---

If `updates` array and `updatesTask` array have equal number of items and you want to display them one by one you can use this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        // Updates
        let cell:updateTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! updateTableViewCell
        let update = updates[indexPath.row/2]
        cell.nameLabel.text = update.addedByUser
        return cell
    } else {
        // UpdatesTask
        let cellTask:tasksTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tasksTableViewCell
        let updateTask = updatesTask[indexPath.row/2]
        cellTask.nameLabel.text = updateTask.addedByUser
        return cellTask
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to mix the cells? To show them randomly after each other, instead of all the updates first and the all the updateTasks?

Comment: @D.Finna Do `updates` array and `updatesTask` array have equal number of items?

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood what you meant by equal number of items! No, you cannot be certain, that the number of items in updates and updatesTask is equal to each other

Answer (score 3):

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        switch section {
        case 0:
            return updates.count
        case 1:
            return updatesTask.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }    

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! updateTableViewCell
            let update = updates[indexPath.row]

            cell.nameLabel.text = update.addedByUser

            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tasksTableViewCell
            let updateTask = updatesTask[indexPath.row]

            cell.nameLabel.text = updateTask.addedByUser

            return cell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For each row you have to choose if you want to display one type of cell or the other but not both. You should have a flag in numberOfRowsInSection telling your method that you want to load Cell or CellTask and then return the correct number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve. If you want to display the number of cells updates[] and updatesTask[] have elements you can do it like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (updates.count + updatesTask.count)
}
```

then you can modify your cellForRowAtIndexPath method like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:updateTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! updateTableViewCell
    let cellTask:tasksTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tasksTableViewCell

if indexPath.row < updates.count{
 //update 
 let update = updates[indexPath.row]
 cell.nameLabel.text = update.addedByUser
}else{
    let updateTask = updatesTask[indexPath.row]
    cellTask.nameLabel.text = updateTask.addedByUser 
}

    return cell
}
```

with the if condition you can choose from which array you are taking data.
But be careful to name an array exactly the same as another constant like you did here

```
let updateTask = updatesTask[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: I will try your code, as I believe it really will help me with my problem.. But just tell me, shouldn't the `>` be the other way round? Like this `<`? If not, please tell me why, as I believe it will only make sence to put it the other way around :-)

Comment: The app crashes as it unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value. The error is here: `if indexPath.row > updates.count{` and both indexPath.row and updates.count is printing 0

Comment: you just posted this snippet. You have to post your whole class if you want a complete answer. You probably did not initialize your array you are asking for inside the class.

Comment: The weird part is, if I get rid of the cellTask completely in my code, I am able to show my feed with the one custom cell? It does not make sence to me.

Comment: maybe you should read the apple documentation of UITableView first to get a better understanding how this works https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview

Answer (score 0):

You should return `total number of rows` in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method. so you can return `summation` of your both array's count something like,

```
 return updates.count + updatesTask.count
```

now in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you can differentiate your cell something like,

```
    let cell:updateTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! updateTableViewCell
    let cellTask:tasksTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tasksTableViewCell



    if indexPath.row % 2 == 1 {

        //your second cell - configure and return
        return cellTask
    }
    else
    {

    //your first cell - configured and return
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple View Model, that will hold the multiple item types:

```
enum ViewModelItemType {
   case nameAndPicture
   case about
   case email
   case friend
   case attribute
}

protocol ViewModelItem {
   var type: ViewModelItemType { get }
   var rowCount: Int { get }
   var sectionTitle: String  { get }
}
```

Then create a model item type for each section. For example:

```
class ViewModelNameAndPictureItem: ViewModelItem {
   var type: ProfileViewModelItemType {
      return .nameAndPicture
   }

   var sectionTitle: String {
      return “Main Info”
   }

   var rowCount: Int {
      return 1
   }

   var pictureUrl: String
   var userName: String

   init(pictureUrl: String, userName: String) {
      self.pictureUrl = pictureUrl
      self.userName = userName
   }
}
```

Once you configure all your section items with, you can save them in ViewModel:

```
class ProfileViewModel {
   var items = [ViewModelItem]()
}
```

And add to you TableViewController:

```
let viewModel = ViewModel()
```

In this case, NumberOfSections, NumberOfRows and CellForRowAt methods will be clean and simple:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return viewModel.items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return viewModel.items[section].rowCount
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = viewModel.items[indexPath.section]
    switch item.type {
          // configure celll for each type
    }
}
```

Configuring the section title will also be very neat:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
   return viewModel.items[section].sectionTitle
}
```

Please check my recent tutorial on this topic, that will answer your question with the details and examples:

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429