# How to create iOS Facebook layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, layout, cells

I want to create layout like Facebook as the image below.

1. How to set distance between 2 cells?
2. Should I use tableview inside of view controller? or other methods?

[image]

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216839/how-to-add-spacing-between-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take A simple Table view and add Cell's as per your needs. the size and all can be defined by yourself so you will be able to get the layout like u have described.