# How can I achieve rowspan in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, ipad

Please see image below, the image is currently done in HTML and CSS, I want to achieve similar result in `UITableView`, in some cells I want to show banner advertisement so I will to do some sort of rowspan for 3 cells, any clue how can I achieve this?

Please note the data is coming via webservice and it have scrollable pagination implemented, so making one custom cell containing group of cell ideas wont work, let me know how to achieve this, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216839/how-to-add-spacing-between-uitableviewcell).
In a few words - move every cell to its own section and implement methods `heightForHeaderInSection` and `viewForHeaderInSection` for your tableView