# How to add space between rows in NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm trying to add spaces in between rows in an NSTableView, like how it looks [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTTZ5.png).

Currently, however, my rows look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPYYr.png), with 0 spacing between them.

Is it possible to add these spaces? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216839/how-to-add-spacing-between-uitableviewcell) on how to do it, but that's for UITableView, and I don't think you can add sections with NSTableView. Another thing I tried was using [intercellSpacing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1524258-intercellspacing) on the table view, like so:

```
tableView.intercellSpacing = NSSize(width: 0, height: 80)
```

However, that just increases the height of each row rather than increase the space between them.

Lastly, I looked into [drawSeparator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstablerowview/1525167-drawseparator), which seems promising but has limited documentation. Would extending NSTableRowView and overriding the drawSeparator method work, basically by drawing in a blank space as the separator? If so, how would I go about making my table view use my custom row view class?

If none of these options work, I'd also be open to faking the effect, maybe by having the actual content of a row be smaller than the row itself and using the remaining space as the padding between rows. However, I'm not sure if this would work, given that right now I'm using NSShadow, which highlights the boundary of each row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way to work around this issue. Before, each row consisted of two columns, one for the text fields and one for the buttons. However, I've changed it by putting all the text fields and buttons into a single column, that way there's only one cell per row. I then can apply the NSShadow and other styles to the NSTableCellView rather than the NSTableRowView. This means that I can now use intercellSpacing to create vertical spacing between cells:

```
tableView.intercellSpacing = NSSize(width: 0, height: 80)
```

The rows are still touching, but I've disabled the borders/highlighting on them so you can't actually see them. The cells, on the other hand, *are* visible, and you can adjust the spacing/styles on them as necessary.