# How to set space between tableView Cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift5

Implemented Programmatically Custom Cell

I am trying to set space between cells but this code is not working for me

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    bounds = bounds.inset(by: padding)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add spacing between UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216839/how-to-add-spacing-between-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Can’t increase cell separator size. You just increase cell height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach is the most simple way that make your cells height a bit bigger(3pt from top and 7pt from the bottom) than that of your cell's Total height, and making the colour as [UIColor clearColor]. That would give the illusion that the cells have a 10 pt gap in between.

**OR**

Add `UIView()` of 10 height at the end and give it clear color it show space between two cells