# How do I highlight tableView cells using Rx and nested cell views?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have a `cell` structure that looks like this:

[image]

The `contentView` has the same `backgroundColor` as the `tableView` `background` (blue) and the nested `view` has a white color with `cornerRadius` and 5p `autoLayout` margin all around, resulting in what looks like separated `cells`, sort of like separated `buttons` in a row (let me know if you need an image).

Whenever I click a `cell` I would like that `cell` to be highlighted with another color. Normally this would be done in the `storyBoard` under the `attribute inspector` `selection`. But this is strictly connected to the `cell` and doesn't effect the nested `views`. I can make the `views` transparent or remove them altogether and it works, but then I miss out on the illusion of separated `cells`.

I read here 
[How to add spacing between UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216839/how-to-add-spacing-between-uitableviewcell) 
that you can use `sections` to separate the `cells`. Nice, but the thing is I'm using `RxSwift` and if I want the `numberOfSections` `delegate`, then I also need `cellForRowAt` and `numberOfRows` and those sort of conflict with my `Rx` `tableView`.

I tried doing it programmatically by adding a `tag` to my nested `view`, fetching it like this:

```
var myView = self.contentView.viewWithTag(1) //self is cell
```

and then set the `color` in the `Rx` `subscription`:

```
    cell?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
```

But this just didn't work. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the method `func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` in the cell and adjust the views how you want based on the `selected` attribute.

Alternatively, you could do this with `rx.methodInvoked` if you don't want to override the method.

At request, here is how to do it with `rx.methodInvoked`.

```
_ = rx.setSelected
    .map { $0.selected ? UIColor.gray : UIColor.white }
    .takeUntil(rx.deallocating)
    .bind(to: contentView.viewWithTag(1)!.rx.backgroundColor)
```

to make the above work, add the code below somewhere:

```
extension Reactive where Base: UITableViewCell {
    var setSelected: Observable<(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)> {
        base.rx.methodInvoked(#selector(UITableViewCell.setSelected(_:animated:)))
        .map { (selected: $0[0] as! Bool, animated: $0[1] as! Bool) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's really nice! It worked great :) Thanks for the tip! In setSelected, I added `if selected {
   self.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
  } else {
   self.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  }`

Comment: Oh, how does it work with rx.methodInvoked by the way? Would be nice to know :)