# How to have a separator drawn in the "middle" of 2 sections space?

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to have separator drawn in `UITableView` with the following condition.

- There is no separators between cell items.
- There is 1 separator between sections.
- There should be space in between the sections.
- The separator between the sections, should be drawn in the middle of section space.

This is how our desired look, in Android app

[image]

---

However, when we implement this in `UITableViewController`, we can hardly make the separator drawn **in the middle** of Section space.

This is how our iOS app looks like

[image]

Here's the custom code, which tries to draw separator between Sections

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // UIView with darkGray background for section-separators as Section Footer
    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 1))
    v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    return v
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // Section Footer height
    return 1.0
}
```

---

The outcome isn't perfect. As you can see, instead of having the separator **in the middle** of "Trash" and "Settings", the separator is closed to "Trash".

---

### Basic data strucrure

Our implementation is pretty straightforward. It looks as following

```
private static let noteSection = [
    SideMeu(
        stringResource: "nav_notes",
        image: UIImage(systemName: "note")!
    )
]

private static let archiveSection = [
    SideMeu(
        stringResource: "nav_archive",
        image: UIImage(systemName: "archivebox")!
    ),
    SideMeu(
        stringResource: "nav_trash",
        image: UIImage(systemName: "trash")!
    )
]

private static let settingsSection = [
    SideMeu(
        stringResource: "nav_settings",
        image: UIImage(systemName: "gear")!
    ),
    SideMeu(
        stringResource: "nav_feedback",
        image: UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.bubble")!
    ),
    SideMeu(
        stringResource: "nav_shop",
        image: UIImage(systemName: "cart")!
    )
]

static let sections = [
    noteSection,
    archiveSection,
    settingsSection
]

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return SideMenuTableViewController.sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let s = SideMenuTableViewController.sections[section]
    return s.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let s = SideMenuTableViewController.sections[indexPath.section]
    let item = indexPath.item
    let sideMenu = s[item]
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = sideMenu.stringResource.localized
    cell.imageView?.image = sideMenu.image
    
    return cell
}
```

---

Do you have any idea, how we can have a nice separator, drawn in the "middle" of 2 sections space? Thanks.

Comment: please change y position to 10 in viewForFooterInSection and try.

Comment: otherwise you can set `contentinset` and i think it's best solution.

Comment: check here for inset: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36060215/9137841

Comment: If you want to use `viewForFooterInSection`, I'd use a `viewForHeaderInSection` too: header of height 5, a footer of height 5 with a "black line" of 1 px on it (to place correctly) instead. Your current setting (height of 1 and black) make your current result, and that's normal, no?